# Loading of a View with an UIActivityIndicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, spinner, activity-indicator

I have an `UITableView` with some `UITableViewCells` and when I click on a specific cell the application will download some information from my server. The question is: "How can I show IMMEDIATELY* a view with only an `UIActivityIndicator` which is animated during all the time of the download and stops its animation when the download is complete?"

*Note: It should not be after other strange operations from the app, it must be the first thing after the click on the cell.

Comment: Check This.. https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD ...

Comment: If you want to do this by using any readymade third party library then just google Activity Indicator/Progress/Loader etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method which starts and stops the activity indicator on main thread in a single method

```
- (void)showIndicatorAndStartWork
{

// start the activity indicator (you are now on the main queue)
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // do your background code here

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // stop the activity indicator (you are now on the main queue again)  
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        });
    });
}
```

**Note**:

I am doing some background stuff so I have used `dispatch_async`, if you also want to download something in background you can also use `dispatch_async` else you can also download the stuff on main thread.